# Can we use AudioEngine on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I am porting a Windows XNA app to Windows Phone.  It uses AudioEngine, SoundBank, Cue and WaveBank.

I am getting compile errors on Windows Phone 7 for these objects.  Are these supported on Windows 7?  If not, what's the path to port this stuff?

```
    private Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.AudioEngine audioEngine;
    private SoundBank soundBank;
    private WaveBank waveBank;
    private Cue musicCue;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your previous question, no, XACT isn't supported on Windows Phone 7. MSDN (and Google search) is very clear about that.

And as for porting it, I recommend you read this blog post: [Playing with Sound on XNA 4 WP7](http://netindonesia.net/blogs/shieny/archive/2010/06/22/playing-with-sound-on-xna-4-wp7.aspx).

Next time, try do a little research yourself ;-)